# How to install Skype on 15.10

Tags: software-installation, skype, repository, 15.10

Before when installing Skype I would just do:

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

However in 15.10 I just get this:

```
E: Unable to locate package skype
```

So will Skype be made available in the repositories for 15.10 soon? Or do I have to install it by some other means? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open **Software & Updates** --> Enable **Canonical Partners repository**

   [image: Imgur]
2. **Reload** (or execute : `sudo apt-get update`)

   [image: Imgur]
3. Open a terminal and execute :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install skype
   ```

Answer (score 7):

Install Skype by executing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

That's it ! ... no less - no more ... **;)**

Comment: I case of `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  skype :
     Depends:
       skype-bin
     E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` error do one more step before apt-get update: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`.